# Wiremock - standalone - proxy authorization header

Tags: wiremock, wiremock-standalone

I'm using standalone wiremock and I'm creating a proxy mapping.
The proxy target requires bearer authentication and the token expires every 5 minute.
I don't want to use the static value of the token inside the proxy mapping because it would require to change it every 5 minutes, what I want to do is to proxy the Authorization header as well.
What I'm trying is:

```
{
  "priority": 10,
  "request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPattern": "/path/.*"
  },
  "response": {
    "proxyBaseUrl": "https://myBaseUrl.com",
    "additionalProxyRequestHeaders": {
      "Authorization": "{{request.headers.Authorization[0]}}"
    },
    "transformers": ["response-template"]
  }
}
```

but the header is not proxied.
Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Headers are normally passed through from the request so just dropping additionalProxyRequestHeaders entirely should permit this.